# Directiva vue 3 usando beforeMount

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue3, directivas

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde recibo un array de permisos desde el backend y los cargo en una funcion, luego aplico directivas en mi main.js de vue 3, en mi componente.vue aplico la directiva v-can y funciona perfecto, el problema que tengo es que cuando cargo mi componente, se muestra el boton que verifica el permiso y en una fraccion de segundo se elimina o desaparece. Estuve revisando y probando un codigo donde agregue un permiso al localStorage y llamo al access.js que tiene este beforeMount, con esto funciona perfecto, no se muestra. el problema esta en que no se como aplicarlo en mi funcion access_permissions de mi composable usePermissions.js

este es mi codigo:

access.js (que utilizo para ejemplo con cargar un permiso en el localStorage)

```
const access_permissions = {
    beforeMount(el, binding) {
      const permissions = localStorage.getItem('permissions');
  
      if (!permissions.includes(binding.value)) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  };
  
  export { access_permissions };
```

luego mi usePermissions.js

```
import { reactive, toRefs } from 'vue'
import useAxios from './useAxios'

export default function () {
    const tenant = localStorage.getItem('tenancy');
    
    const state = reactive({
        user: null,
        photo: null,
        permisos: null
    });

    const profile = async () => {
        const request = await useAxios(
            `${tenant}/api/user`,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        );
        state.user = await request.sendRequest();
    };

    //Aca deberia utilizar el beforeMount
    const access_permissions = async (el, binding) => {
        await profile();

        const permissions = state.user.permissions.map(permission => permission.name);
        const userId = state.user.id;
      
        if (userId && binding.value && parseInt(userId) === parseInt(binding.value)) {
          return;
        }
      
        if (!permissions.includes(binding.value)) {
          el.remove();
        }
      
        console.log(permissions);
      };     
    
    return { 
        ...toRefs(state), 
        profile, 
        access_permissions
    };
}
```

Aqui al tener esta funcion access_permissions en async await no logro aplicarle el beforeMount, mas bien no se como aplicarlo para solucionar mi problema

y finalmente mi main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router/router';
import store from './store/store';
import storeTenant from './store/Tenant/store';
import './index.css';
import moment from  'moment';
import usePermissions from './composables/Tenant/usePermissions';

const { access_permissions } = usePermissions();

const app = createApp(App);

//import { access_permissions } from './composables/Tenant/acess';
//localStorage.setItem('permissions', 'list coowner')

app.use(store);
app.use(storeTenant);
app.use(router);
app.use(moment);

app.directive('can', access_permissions);

//console.log(access_permissions)  

app.mount('#app');
```

aca cero problema, y finalmente en mi componente.vue utilizo la directiva

```
<router-link to="visits/create" v-can="'list coowner'">
   <button class="bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 text-white font-bold py-2 mt-6 px-2 md:w-1/8 mx-2 rounded w-48">Crear registro</button>
</router-link>
```

Espero haber sido claro en mi explicacion de mi problema y lo que deseo hacer y solucionar

Comment: No respondió al aporte de su pregunta anterior en esta etiqueta -VUE-. ¿Qué se espera de esta si no tiene en cuenta las respuestas?

Comment: Sorry bro que que no revise la respuesta a fondo en su momento, ya que habia estado viendo otras cosas de codigo, logre resolverlo y de la misma forma que lo habias mencionado, ahora estoy quedandome con un ultimo detalle que menciono en esta pregunta para resolver esto! Gracias bro!